# FileDescriptor:error android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I know this is a quite common question, however I am struggling with getting the output. Below is my code:

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/JackPowell/AndroidStudioProjects/Shaker/app/src/main/res/raw/na.mp3"));

        FileDescriptor fd = fileInputStream.getFD();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error shows that the directory does not exist. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Users/JackPowell/AndroidStudioProjects/Shaker/app/src/main/res/raw/na.mp3` is a path for a file on an OS X machine. AFAIK, there are zero Android devices on this planet that have a `/Users` directory off the root.

My guess is that you are attempting to read in a raw resource. In that case, use `Resources` and its `openRawResource()` method, passing in `R.raw.na`. You can get a `Resources` object from any `Context` (such as your activity) via `getResources()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Would you mind show me an example solution as a future reference ? thanks

Comment: @JackPowell: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.6/WidgetCatalog/ExpandableListView/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/wc/elv/MainActivity.java#L43

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.na);
     try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mPlayer.prepare;
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```